# URL format of IOS deeplinking,

Tags: ios

I needed to know, how we can have a URL in such a way that, if application is installed, navigate to application, if not navigate fallback url(any uRL).

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not related to programming issue

Comment: You can also find guides [here](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) and [here](http://blog.hokolinks.com/how-to-implement-apple-universal-links-on-ios-9/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Universal Links. Refer to the guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)